# Java. try catch подсвечивается

Tags: java, try-catch

подсвечивается *try catch: unexpected token.*

В чем может быть проблема?

```
public class Class7 {

  String[] mas = new String[10];

  try {
    System.out.println(" ");
    mas[10]=" ";
  }
  catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("Выход за пределы массива");
  }

  Class7(int length) {
    this.mas = new String[length];
  }
}
```

Comment: Конструкция `try/catch` должна находиться внутри метода.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш **try/catch** находится в описании класса, а не в описании метода. Попробуйте так:

```
public class Class7 {

  String[] mas = new String[10];

  Class7(int length) {
    this.mas = new String[length];

    try {
        System.out.println(" ");
        mas[10]=" ";
      }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Выход за пределы массива");
    }
  }
}
```